# TFS Current Sprint URL

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there a URL that I can bookmark for my team's TFS *Current Sprint* task board? We have 2-week sprints so the URL changes every 2 weeks.

The default URL is of the form:

```
http://[Server]/tfs/[Project]/[Team]/_backlogs/TaskBoard/[SprintName]#_a=people
```

The `[SprintName]` part of the URL changes every sprint, thus it doesn't provide a stable URL. I'm wondering if there's some version of the URL that always points to the current sprint, i.e.:

```
http://[Server]/tfs/[Project]/[Team]/_backlogs/TaskBoard/CURRENT#_a=people
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just found the answer. If you remove the sprint name altogether, it redirects to the current sprint.

> **EDIT**: Updated Oct. 2018 for Azure DevOps

For Azure DevOps, the following URL works:

New Azure DevOps URL format:

```
https://dev.azure.com/[Company]/[Project]/_sprints/backlog/[Team]
```

Old Azure DevOps (VSTS) URL format:

```
https://[Company].visualstudio.com/[Project]/_sprints/taskboard/[Team]/
```

Previously in TFS, the URL was:

```
http://[Server]/tfs/[Project]/[Team]/_backlogs/TaskBoard#_a=people
```

Comment: http://[Server]/tfs/[Project]/[Team]/_backlogs/Iteration for the current sprint backlog.

Comment: This approach works for VSTS as well (e.g., `https://[Tenant].visualstudio.com/[Project]/_backlogs/Iteration`), but it takes noticeably longer to load.

Comment: I believe the VSTS (Now Azure Dev Ops) link is no longer working. Any updates on this?

Comment: URL in answer works, URL in comment does not work, in my Azure DevOps (VSTS).

Comment: A slightly different URL worked for me in VSTS (now Azure DevOps): `https://[Company].visualstudio.com/[Project]/_sprints/taskboard/[Team]/` That was based on the text description of how to edit the URL (i.e. remove the current sprint path, leaving just the team reference)

Comment: Thanks @ncoghlan; I've incorporated this into the answer.

Comment: In the context of Microsoft, this makes total sense.

Comment: Thank you!!! The new Azure DevOps Url worked for me!

Comment: Nice , so simple, didn't think of it :-)