# TFS previous/next sprint URL

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

As a Product Owner, I would like to have three start tabs in my browser. Previous, current and next sprint. Of course without having to change them with each passing sprint.
URL for current sprint for me is:
https://dev.azure.com/[company]/[Project]/_sprints/backlog/[Team]/
(inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163793/tfs-current-sprint-url) post, but slightly modified)

I seek to have same time-independent link to previous and next sprint. Is there a URL like above for this, can I make a query that I can call using a URL or another solution?